# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (while calling a js function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass multiple values as a parameter on click event as below:

```
<c:forEach var="ct" items="${contactmsglist}">
  <li class="msgList" id="${ct.getContactId()}" onclick="sendId(${ct.getContactId()},${ct.getName()})">
  </li>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I resolve that error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

after argument list.

Comment: If the values being injected are strings you'll need to enclose them in quotes

Comment: is ${ct.getContactId()} calling directly and javascript function it looks like ${} is a variable wrapper for coldfusion?, jsp?, isml? or prehaps you need quotation marks around the output if they are template variables meant to be output as a string

Answer (score -1):

Try adding quote arround your arguments if they are string :

```
<c:forEach var="ct" items="${contactmsglist}">
    <li class="msgList" id="${ct.getContactId()}" 
        onclick="sendId('${ct.getContactId()}','${ct.getName()}')">
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's the problem here

Answer (score -1):

Single quote missing, I think thats the issue here

```
    <c:forEach var="ct" items="${contactmsglist}">
    <li class="msgList" id="${ct.getContactId()}" 
    onclick="sendId('${ct.getContactId()}',
     '${ct.getName()}')">
     </li>
   </c:forEach>
```